# Handle photos in media group using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm building a test echo bot and I'm running into a problem getting all files from one media group as each group file is a separate message.

Is it possible to find out which media group message is the latest? Or is there some other way to get all files from one media group?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please have a look at [this faq entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-requested-design-patterns#how-do-i-deal-with-a-media-group) of the ptb wiki